# Problem with intersection of two paths

Tags: tikz-pgf

I can not get the attached figure.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,11pt,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc,intersections}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}{thick,x=0.5cm,y=0.5cm}

\coordinate [label=below left  : $A$](A) at (0,0);
\coordinate [label=below right : $B$](B) at (10,0);
\coordinate [label=above left : $C$] (C) at (0,5);

\path[name path=line1] (C.east) -- (C.east-|B.west)coordinate[pos=0.6](N) ;
\path[name path=line2] (A) -- (B);
\path[name path=line3]($(A)!(N)!(B)$) -- (N);
\path[name path=line4]($(C)!(N)!(A)$) -- (N);
\path[name path=line5] (A) -- (C);

\path[name intersections={of=line1 and line3,by={P}}];
\path[name intersections={of=line1 and line5,by={M}}];

\draw[fill=green] (A-|P) --(N) -- (C-|M) -- (A) --cycle;
\draw (A)--(B)--(C)--cycle;

\node[above] at (N){$N$};
\node[below] at (P){$P$};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Off-topic but anchors have no meaning if the node is just a coordinate.

Comment: You only need `\path (C) -- (B)coordinate[pos=0.6](N) ;
\draw[fill=green] (A) rectangle (N);`

Comment: @marmot, your solution is much easier using `rectangle`.

Comment: @sigur but you were much faster +1 (my internet is really slow these days... )

Comment: @marmot, if you keep that rep/day ratio with low internet, what happens if you get full speed !

Comment: @BambOo There is reputation cap and I am only affected but this temporarily... ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just control the position of `P` between `A` and `B`. I used 60%.

```
\documentclass[tikz,11pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc,intersections}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,x=0.5cm,y=0.5cm]

\coordinate [label=below left  : $A$](A) at (0,0);
\coordinate [label=below right : $B$](B) at (10,0);
\coordinate [label=left  : $C$](C) at (0,5);
\coordinate [label=below : $P$](P) at ($(A)!.6!(B)$);

\path[name path=hipo]  (C) -- (B);
\path[name path=rightVertical] (P) -- (P|-C) ;
\path[name path=leftVertical] (A) -- (C);

\path[name intersections={of=rightVertical and hipo,by={N}}];
\path[name path=horizontal] (N) -- (N-|C) ;
\path[name intersections={of=horizontal and leftVertical,by={M}}];

\draw[fill=green] (P)--(N)--(M)--(A)--cycle;
\draw (A)--(B)--(C)--cycle;
\node[above] at (N){$N$};
\node[left]  at (M){$M$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You could also fix `\begin{tikzpicture}{...}` to `\begin{tikzpicture}[...]`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. good point. Done!

Answer (score 13):

Similar to @Sigur but there are no intersections used (as not needed).

```
\documentclass[tikz,11pt,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,x=0.5cm,y=0.5cm]
\coordinate [label=below left  : $A$](A) at (0,0);
\coordinate [label=below right : $B$](B) at (10,0);
\coordinate [label=above left : $C$] (C) at (0,5);
\path (C) -- (B)coordinate[pos=0.6,label=above right:$N$](N) ;
\draw[fill=green] (A) rectangle (N);
\coordinate[label=above left:$M$] (M) at (A|-N);
\draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output as your desired screen shot.

[image]

Comment: @manooooh added (really slow internet in Mexico.. )

Comment: Not too slow. I was preparing the output for you, but you were faster... lol

Comment: @marmot Thank you, your solution is much simpler than the one I proposed !